# Shader Storage Buffer Object has zero length, glMapBufferRange not working

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I've been trying to implement tiled deferred shading and I've been stuck on a problem for some time now. I'm trying to store an array of structs consisting of point lights that I want to initalize and send to a compute shader where I can process it further. I'm using a Shader Storage Buffer Object for this and I'm trying to use glMapBufferRange to provide the values. I've added some checks so that if the array size is 0 I'll paint the screen red and if it's larger than 0 it's yellow, so far I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the compute shader:

```
#version 430
#define MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE 16
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 1280.0f
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 720.0f


uniform sampler2D positionMap;
uniform sampler2D colorMap;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;
uniform sampler2D depthMap;

layout(binding = 4, rgba32f) uniform writeonly image2D finalImage;
layout(binding = 5, rgba32f) uniform writeonly image2D otherImage;

struct PointLight
{
    vec3 position; //4,8,12
    vec3 color; // 16,20, 24
    float radius; //28
    float diffuseIntensity; //32
    float ambientIntensity; //36
    float Constant; //40
    float Linear; //44
    float Exp; //48
};

layout(std430, binding = 6) buffer BufferObject
{
    PointLight pointLights[];
};

shared uint minDepth;
shared uint maxDepth;

layout(local_size_x = MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, local_size_y = MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE)in;

void main()
{

    if(gl_LocalInvocationIndex == 0){
        minDepth = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        maxDepth = 0;
    }
    ivec2 pixelPos = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    vec2 uv = vec2(pixelPos.x / SCREEN_WIDTH, pixelPos.y / SCREEN_HEIGHT);


    float d = texture(depthMap,uv).z;

    uint depth = uint(d * 0xFFFFFFFF);

    //compares the content of minDepth to depth and writes the minimum value to minDepth
    atomicMin(minDepth, depth);
//  barrier();
//compares the content of maxDepth to depth and writes the maximum value to the      maxDepth
    atomicMax(maxDepth, depth);



    ///Write a single texel into an image
/*  barrier();
    imageStore(finalImage, pixelPos, vec4(float(float(maxDepth) / float(0xFFFFFFFF))));

    barrier();
    imageStore(otherImage, pixelPos, vec4(float(float(minDepth) / float(0xFFFFFFFF))));
    */

    PointLight p = pointLights[0];
    PointLight p2 = pointLights[1];
    if(pointLights.length() == 0)
    {
        barrier();
        imageStore(finalImage, pixelPos, vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0));

        barrier();
        imageStore(otherImage, pixelPos, vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0));
    }
    if(pointLights.length() > 0)
    {
        barrier();
        imageStore(finalImage, pixelPos, vec4(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0));

        barrier();
        imageStore(otherImage, pixelPos, vec4(1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0));
    }

}
```

Here's how I'm trying to initalize the buffer with some test values:

```
My3dVector currentColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    glGenBuffers(1,&m_pointLightBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,m_pointLightBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,NUM_OF_LIGHTS*sizeof(struct TDPointLight), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

struct TDPointLight* pointlights = (struct TDPointLight*) glMapBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, NUM_OF_LIGHTS*sizeof(struct TDPointLight), GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT );

int shit = ARRAY_SIZE_IN_ELEMENTS(pointlights);
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_LIGHTS; ++i)
{
    float Max  = 80.0f;
    float Min = -80.0f;

    float MaxZ = 80.0f;
    float MinZ = -80.0f;

    float ranx = ((float(rand()) / float(RAND_MAX)) * (Max - Min)) + Min;
    float ranz = ((float(rand()) / float(RAND_MAX)) * (Max - Min)) + Min;

    int maxCol = 8;
    int minCol = 1;
    //int ranCol = ((rand() / RAND_MAX) * (maxCol - minCol)) + minCol;
    int ranCol = (rand()%(maxCol-minCol))+minCol;

    if(ranCol == 0)
        printf("error, color 8 doesnt exist");
    if(ranCol == 1)
        currentColor = COLOR_WHITE;
    if(ranCol == 2)
        currentColor = COLOR_RED;
    if(ranCol == 3)
        currentColor = COLOR_GREEN;
    if(ranCol == 4)
        currentColor = COLOR_CYAN;
    if(ranCol == 5)
        currentColor = COLOR_BLUE;
    if(ranCol == 6)
        currentColor = COLOR_PURPLE;
    if(ranCol == 7)
        currentColor = COLOR_ORANGE;
    if(ranCol == 8)
        printf("error, color 8 doesnt exist");

    pointlights[i].position = My3dVector(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    pointlights[i].color = My3dVector(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    pointlights[i].radius = 10.0f;
    pointlights[i].diffuseIntensity = 10.0f;
    pointlights[i].ambientIntensity = 0.1f;
    //pointlights[i].color = currentColor;
    //pointlights[i].position = My3dVector(ranx,3.0f,ranz);
    //m_pointLight[i].m_Position = My3dVector(0.0f,2.0f,0.0f);
    pointlights[i].Constant = 0.0f;
    pointlights[i].Linear = 0.0f;
    pointlights[i].Exp = 0.6f;
}
glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER);
```

Then the process goes something like:

1. Use the compute shader
2. Set all the uniforms, then bind some deferred textures and other things using this code

   ```
   for(unsigned int i = 0; i<ARRAY_SIZE_IN_ELEMENTS(m_textures); ++i) 
   {
       glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[TDGBuffer_TEXTURE_TYPE_POSITION + i]);
   }
   glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program,"depthMap"),3);
   glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,m_depthTexture);

   //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
   //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,m_finalTexture);
   glBindImageTexture(4, m_finalTexture, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);

   glBindImageTexture(5,m_otherTexture,0,GL_FALSE,0,GL_WRITE_ONLY,GL_RGBA32F);
   glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER,6,m_pointLightBuffer);
   ```

Then finally in the main loop call these functions

```
glDispatchCompute((window_width/MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE), (window_height/MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE), 1);
glFinish();
```

It doesn't work with any memory barriers anywhere in the code, but as I'm not modifying the contents anywhere this shouldn't be a problem as it just gets initialized once and then remains the same forever.

Comment: Your alignment for the `PointLight` struct is wrong. Two `vec3`s do not tightly pack together, they are aligned to a `vec4` boundary. You should re-arrange your data structure slightly and place one of your `float`s in-between the two `vec3`s.

Comment: Also, why did you tag this OpenGL ES? ES does not have compute shaders.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll fix the tags, must've missed that bit. I tried rearranging everything so I had a float in between the vec3s and then changed my TDPointlight struct to have the same order but it produced the same results unfortunately

Comment: Yeah, I did not think that was going to fix your problem, but it was definitely against the `std140`/`std430` alignment rules. The only thing 430 changed was that the size of each element in an array of structs does not have to be as rigid, so end padding (which is not an issue in this case since the whole thing is a multiple of 4N) does not have to be added.

Comment: I've been following this presentation http://education.siggraph.org/media/conference/S2012_Materials/ComputeShader_1pp.pdf and I tried to intialize the data and then just use glBufferData and instead of adding NULL I added the array which didn't work either. I'm just not really sure where to look, I activate the compute shader program before I try and bind the buffers as well, really have no idea why they would have zero length

Answer (score 0):

It appears I've just made a silly mistake. After rearranging the structs to match the size of vec4s I can print out the correct color and position by using

```
PointLight p = pointLights[3];
PointLight p2 = pointLights[55];

//vec3 test = vec3(p.posX,p.posY,p.posZ);
//vec3 test2 = vec3(p2.posX,p2.posY,p2.posZ);
vec4 test = p.color;
vec4 test2 = p2.color;

barrier();
imageStore(finalImage, pixelPos, test);

barrier();
imageStore(otherImage, pixelPos, test2);
```

I still get a zero size from length but I believe that's because the shader doesn't know that the size of the array has been updated